# app/main.js throwing 404 when deployed to heroku?

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I created a public folder to hold my js and css files.  I also had some node_modules that I needed to make accessible so I made that directory public.  Now when I run the app which is located here : https://sleepy-anchorage-14491.herokuapp.com/, it tells me it can't find `app\main.js`.

Here is my index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <base href="/">
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));


var server = require('http').createServer(app);


server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

// When the root director is requested, return the index.html page.
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "angulardemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "angulardemo",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.5",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Already Late for the answer but still 
try to update your package.json file
 1. move all devDependencies to dependencies
 2. add engines which node and npm verion you have used locally it will tell heroku to install those version on server

```
{ 
 "name": "angulardemo",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": 
 "angulardemo",
 "main": "server.js",
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node app.js",
 "postinstall": "ng build --prod",
 "build": "ng build"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "MIT",
 "dependencies": {
 "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
 "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
 "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
 "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
 "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
 "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
 "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
 "core-js": "^2.4.1",
 "ejs": "^2.5.5",
 "express": "^4.14.1",
 "rxjs": "5.0.1",
 "systemjs": "0.19.40",
 "zone.js": "^0.7.4",
 "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
 "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
 "typescript": "~2.0.10",
 "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
 "http-server": "^0.9.0",
 "tslint": "^3.15.1",
 "lodash": "^4.16.4",
 "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
 "karma": "^1.3.0",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
 "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
 "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
 "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
 "protractor": "~4.0.14",
 "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
 "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
 "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
 },
 "engines": {
 "node": "6.11.1", --> write your npm version to tell heroku which version to install there (command: node -v) 
 "npm": "3.10.10" --> command: npm -v
 }
}
```

3. in your app.module.component file inside @NgModule add 
    `**bootstrap: [RootComponent]**`  
    it will tell angular to load root component all other components should be declared inside 
   if you have more than one component in index.html you should add all of them in **`bootstrap: [RootComponent,comp1,comp2]`** but it is not good practice. So add only root to bootstrap and make other component child of root.

   **declarations: [
   comp1,
   comp2,
   comp3,
   comp4
   ]**